# Web Scrapping with R for javascript enabled web page. (using rvest and xml2 packages)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrap data from Bloomberg Billionaire Index from link: [https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) . I have tried this code

I have tried this code

```
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("xml2")
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
url <- "https://www.bloomberg.com/billionaires/"
page <- read_html(url)
```

but getting this message when I try to read webpage.

page
{html_document}

[1] \n\nBloomberg - Are you a robot?\n\n\nBloomberg\n    Need help? Contact us\nWe've detec ...

Can anyone please help me to read url effectively so that I can scrap data using html tags.

Comment: The message indicates that they have detected your attempts to scrape the site and prevented it. If the site is designed not to be scraped, there’s not much you can do. This isn’t the right place to ask for help breaking-and-entering where not wanted.

Comment: If you only want to do it once, you can load the page in a browser, save it as an html file to your computer, and then `read_html` the saved file. Or could just cut and paste the table from a browser into another program (such as Excel, or a text editor) and work with that.

Comment: For one-shot data collection, taking cURL string from the browser and converting it to R / httr is probably one of the easiest and fastest routes - https://curlconverter.com/r/